# How to not add the same element in a list

Tags: python, python-3.x

i need you again...

Here is my code :

```
def import_sudoku():
    with open("sudoku.txt") as f:
        lines = f.read()

sudoku = [[character for character in line if not character == " "] for line in lines.split("\n")]

return sudoku

sudoku = import_sudoku()
print(sudoku)
def grid_index(grid, value):
    for i, row in enumerate(grid):
        for j, cell in enumerate(row):
            if cell == value:
                return i, j
    return -1, -1
print("Coords:",grid_index(sudoku, "."))


def solve_next_unsolved(sudoku):
    coords = grid_index(sudoku, ".")
    value_to_input = "3"

    for cell in sudoku[0]:
        if value_to_input == cell:
        break
    else:
        sudoku[coords[0]][coords[0]] = value_to_input



print(sudoku)
```

My sudoku.txt...

```
.3. ... ...
..8 39. 6..
5.1 2.. 49.
.7. 6.. ...
2.. ... .4.
... 5.3 98.
... ... 15.
... ..7 ..9
4.. .1. 3..
```

So, i am working with the first line at the moment. I don't understand why a 3 can be stored in my line... In fact, when i break the while when a 3 is found in the first line, it's not supposed to break the while and end the loop... ??

Last thing : If you see my profil, it is my third post in the same object... (sudoku solver...) it is possible to keep this topic for all my problem and not create a topic every time i have a problem... ?

If someone wants to help me but not just here (and if you have time ... etc), my skype : lakyrorr

Really sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: Your `break` is not inside the `if` block, you have to indent it. Also where is the `while` you mentioned?

Answer (score 1):

Your else belongs to the wrong block: the indentation makes it belong to the for loop and not to the if statement as you probably intended:

```
for cell in sudoku[0]:
    if value_to_input == cell:
        break
    else:
        sudoku[coords[0]][coords[0]] = value_to_input
```

Instead of looping over list elements you can also check

```
if value_to_input in row:
    print "Duplicate entry"
    break
```

To respond to your general question: the way stackoverflow works is to deal with small individual problems. It i snot a forum to discuss larger programming projects whewre the same people would look at your code again from time to time.

Comment: `for cell in sudoku[0]:
  if value_to_input == cell:
   break
 else:
  sudoku[coords[0]][coords[0]] = value_to_input `
This look good nope ?
God damned, not possibility to show you correctly the code i want... That's boring me...